# Magento - Sort name that includes a number

Tags: php, magento, sorting

I'm a novice at programming websites so this may be a dumb question. I have product names that include a number. This in itself is not a problem, the sorting by Magento is.

Magento sorts as follows:

- Product 10
- Product 11
- Product 12
- Product 1
- Product 2
- Product 3

I would like it to sort like this:

- Product 1
- Product 2
- Product 3
- Product 10
- Product 11
- Product 12

Is it possible to fix this? Or am I forced to use 0's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $product_names_array = array("Product 12","Product 11", "Product 10", "Product 1", "Product 2", "Product 3");
    natsort($product_names_array);
    print_r($product_names_array);

Output:

Array
(
    [3] => Product 1
    [4] => Product 2
    [5] => Product 3
    [2] => Product 10
    [1] => Product 11
    [0] => Product 12
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$product_names_array = array("Product 12","Product 11", "Product 10", "Product 1", "Product 2", "Product 3", );

foreach($product_names_array as $product_names_array_value) {    
    $product_number = preg_replace('/\D/s', '', $product_names_array_value);
    $sorted_array[$product_number] = $product_names_array_value;  
    ksort($sorted_array);
}
```